# Publishing page metadata in TeamSite

Tags: metadata, teamsite

I know that you can publish individual page components, such as DCRs and graphics, through a TeamSite workflow, but does anyone know if it's possible to publish page metadata?

Comment: What do you mean by page metadata publish? It can be published to a database of LiveSite Content Server.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about ability to deploy the Metadata to Runtime Livesite Severs, YES you can.

How ?
You need to have the Livesite Content Services ( LSCS Runime ) instance installed on Runtime server which will store the deployed Metadata and content.

Pre-requisite is to Index the Metadata in Teamsite Authoring server.( Search Server ).

Then use the OOB PLC ( Publish Livesite Content ) Workflow to deploy both Static ( to LSDS Server ) and Metadata to ( LSCS Store/Runtime ) based on configurations you have defined.

Once you have the Metadata deployed to LSCS you can query the Metadata / EA to build dynamic content experience ( Ex: Return me all content for the Year 2014 ). So you can aggregate and segregate based on your business need.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed an author submit with metadata workflow out of the box in your /TeamSite/local/config/wft/solutions folder.